# How to find the smallest value in DF between the first and the column that has maximum value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the maximum value of each row and the smallest value before the maximum value in pandas.

Input:

```
   ab  bc  cd  ef  eh  ij
0   1   2  12   4   6   7
1   4   5   6   1  10   4
2   5   6   9   1   2   4
3  12   1   3   1   2   4
```

Expected output:

```
   ab  bc  cd  ef  eh  ij  Max  MinBefore
0   1   2  12   4   6   7   12        1.0
1   4   5   6   1  10   4   10        1.0
2   5   6   9   1   2   4    9        5.0
3  12   1   3   1   2   4   12       12.0
```

I have tried using:

```
df['min_col'] = df.iloc[:, 13:df['max_col_index']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: Please provide your data in a reproducible format

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean masks to find the position of the max and the previous values:

```
# get max per row
max_val = df.max(axis=1)

# identify max and values after
m1 = df.eq(max_val, axis=0)
m2 = ~m1.cummax(axis=1)

# mask values after and get min per row
min_val = df.where(m1 | m2).min(axis=1)

# update DataFrame
df['Max'] = max_val
df['MinBefore'] = min_val
```

Output:

```
   ab  bc  cd  ef  eh  ij  Max  MinBefore
0   1   2  12   4   6   7   12        1.0
1   4   5   6   1  10   4   10        1.0
2   5   6   9   1   2   4    9        5.0
3  12   1   3   1   2   4   12       12.0
```